# Using powerquery to unpivot table with multiple columns into a table with two columns that represent pairs of dates from original table?

Tags: pivot-table, powerquery, unpivot

Imagine I had a 'horizontal' data set that contained:

1. Unique Key
2. Multiple 'pairs' of dates across multiple columns (i.e. Event A Start, Event B Start, Event C Start, etc and separate columns for Event A End, Event B End, Event C End, etc).
3. A single date (not a pair) for a specific 'Event'.

In essence, looks something like this:

**Data Set**

| Unique Key | Event A Start | Event A End | Single Date Event | Event B Start | Event B End | 2nd Single Date Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key 1 | 1 Jan 2021 | 3 Jan 2021 | 2 Jan 2021 | 5 Jan 2021 | 10 Jan 2021 | 10 Jan 2021 |
| Key 2 | 7 Jan 2021 | 10 Jan 2021 | ***null*** | ***null*** | ***null*** | ***null*** |

How would I convert the Data Set above into a table like this using PowerQuery?

**Expected Output:**

| Unique Key | Event | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key 1 | Event A | 1 Jan 2021 | 3 Jan 2021 |
| Key 1 | Single Date Event | ***null*** | 2 Jan 2021 |
| Key 1 | Event B | 5 Jan 2021 | 10 Jan 2021 |
| Key 1 | 2nd Single Date Event | ***null*** | 10 Jan 2021 |
| Key 2 | Event A | 7 Jan 2021 | 10 Jan 2021 |

I've tried:

- **Unpivot** but I can't rename both "Event A Start" and "Event A End" into "Event A". I even tried renaming all "Event [x] Start" as "Event [x]", did a 'unpivot selected' of all "Event [x]'. Then I renamed all "Event [x] End" into "Event [x]" and then performed an unpivot on those columns. Unfortunately, the Key and Event columns don't line up.
- **Merge Query**: I have tried merging one query with another but it's not quite getting the desired output. I created two separate queries (one with Key, Event, and Start Date; another with Key, Event and End Date). But this not having the desired effect. I think this is because of the Single Date Events being 'null'?

I feel I am definitely doing something wrong, so asking here to see if the output that I want is even achievable with PowerQuery based on the input data?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to do a bit of extra work on top of an unpivot.

Here's how I'd approach it:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8k6tVDBU0lEyVPBKzFMwMjACcYyROUbIHFNkjqEBLl6sDsRkI6C4OW4teaU5Odip2FgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Unique Key" = _t, #"Event A Start" = _t, #"Event A End" = _t, #"Single Date Event" = _t, #"Event B Start" = _t, #"Event B End" = _t, #"2nd Single Date Event" = _t]),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Unique Key"}, "Event", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Value", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Event], "Start") then "Start Date" else "End Date"),
    #"Transformed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Event", each if Text.EndsWith(_, "Start") or Text.EndsWith(_, "End") then Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, " ", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}) else _, type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Transformed Text", List.Distinct(#"Transformed Text"[Custom]), "Custom", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Steps:

1. Unpivot the date columns
2. Add a new column to tag each row as Start Date / End Date
3. Strip off " Start" / " End" suffix in the [Event] column
4. Pivot on the new column from Step 2

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Let me just look into this and come back to you. I'm a lawyer by trade who has been asked to help with this Excel project, so learning day by day!

Will get back to you!